# Cannot find window handle

Tags: c++, winapi, code-injection

I want to find the window by name with the code:

```
HANDLE hWnd = FindWindow(0, (LPCWSTR)"Untitled - Notepad");
```

But if I check hWnd afterwards it is always null. What am I doing wrong here?

Both the application and notepad is running in x64

Comment: Ooh, that's a nasty cast. How can you be in doubt what you're doing wrong? You're ***lying to the compiler***, telling it to shut up. Instead, listen to the compiler. Heed its advice.

Comment: I am not allowed to cast like this? I googled before I posted this question and everyone who used this function simple called "Untitled - Notepad" without casting anything but I cannot do that because of the compiler. So I thought I should cast?

Comment: Write that literal as `L"Untitled - Notepad"`. It may not necessarily work for finding the window (it may be wrong, it's very specific), but it's technically correct. A cast says that you know what you're doing, and the compiler trusts you on that - which is ungood when you don't know. ;-)

Comment: yes that's it, thank you :)

Comment: Don't lie to the compiler

Answer (score 3):

`(LPCWSTR)"Untitled - Notepad"` is an invalid type cast. You're incorrectly telling the compiler that the string is a wide string, without telling the compiler to actually compile the string as a wide string (by default it's compiled as an 8-bit narrow string).

The correct solution is to use the `L` prefix instead:

```
HANDLE hWnd = FindWindow(0, L"Untitled - Notepad");
```

This tells the compiler that the string literal is to be wide instead of narrow.